# Removing duplicate entry in RecyclerView : Scrolling Issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

Hello I am calling below function to set data in my **onBindview()** method of Recycler view **Adapter**.

I am calling method as below :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
    holder.setData(position);
}
```

My setData() method is as below :

```
 public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView txt_HappyHour;

        public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txt_HappyHour = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_HappyHour);

        }
        public void setData(final int position) {
                final MyModel.MyData modelMyList = itemList.get(position);

                            if (modelMyList.happy_hours.equals("1")) {
                                txt_HappyHour.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            } else {
                                txt_HappyHour.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                  }
        }
```

I am setting visibility for TextView **txt_HappyHour** according to conditions in above setData() function. Now, When I run the app, I got the Textview visible for more than one or multiple time while Scrolling my RecyclerView.

I heared that I can solve this scrolling issue by using **setTag()** and **getTag()** method. But, I am confused that in my case, How can I use or apply it ?

Need Help.

Comment: Try using getLayoutPosition() or getAdapterPosition() method

Comment: Sir, getAdapterPosition() is not working, I have tried as  final MyModel.MyData modelMyList = itemList.get(getAdapterPosition());

Comment: Where you initialize your txt_HappyHour   @ZapAndi  You have to initialize  text view into your Viewholder class. you view is not binding correctly.

Comment: Hey i am asking where you give id of text view @Zap Andi

Comment: Can you post your model class

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this answer ?

```
 if (null == txt_HappyHour.getTag) {
            txt_HappyHour.setTag(modelMyList.happy_hours);
        }
        String Value = (String) txt_HappyHour.getTag();
        if (Value.equals("1")) {
            txt_HappyHour.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            txt_HappyHour.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
```

Comment: My TaxtView is with custom Border and Background, thats why using VISIBILITY

Comment: Hi @Zap Andi, Now I have edited My code Check it, It may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your onBindViewHolder use setTag like this

```
txt_HappyHour.setTag(position);
```

And in your setData Method

```
if(itemView.get((Integer) txt_HappyHour.getTag()).happy_hours.equals("1"))
{
 txt_HappyHour.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
   txt_HappyHour.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: sir, method : (get)  is not resolving.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and try again....get method takes integer values

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: yes sir, i will post tomorrow. i just removed setData() method and made all its code to onBindViewHolder() method. set tag to my TextView and done getTag with its position.